# GitLab apply image only to one job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have pipeline:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test
  - deploy

deploy-test:
  stage: test
  image: python
  only:
    - /^B[Ii]-.*$/
  script:
     - git --version
     - . PublishPBIReports.sh

deploy-prod:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  image: python
  only:
    - master
  script:
     - git --version
     - pbifiles=(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 -- '***.pbix')
     - echo $pbifiles
     - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

when i push to branches i see in runner logs that runner every time use docker:latest image for branches, but in my master branch he work correct (every time use python image and all work right).

Comment: as far as i understand all new branches execute with new version gitlab-ci.yml with python image, but all old branches run with old version gitlab-ci.yml. Maybe it's stupid question, but can i push new version gitlab-ci.yml to all branches that i have?

Comment: You can cherry pick the commit changing the yaml into your other branches.

Comment: I can't understand that happen, because i created new branch and i see that gitlab-ci.yml with old configuration. Another user created new branch and he received last version gitlab-ci.yml.

I thought that when i create new branch i receive last version gitlab-ci.yml, right?